# How can I exclude Kendo TimePicker from evaluation by Kendo Validator?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

ASP.Net MVC, .NET Framework 4.6.2, Kendo 2019.3.917

I am using the Kendo TimePicker and the Kendo Validator. I am trying to prevent Validator from evaluating TimePicker. The Validator is using attributes set in the Model.

```
        public DateTime OverheadRepeatedByDateTime { get; set; }
```

However, Validator still evaluates. So, I learned somewhere to add a class such as *ignore* and then configure Validator to look for that class on a data item and not evaluate. But that approach doesn't work either. Validator evaluates TimePicker.

```
                @(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
                        .Name("OverheadRepeatedByDateTime")
                        .Interval(5)
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px;", @class = "ignore" })
                )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OverheadRepeatedByDateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

```
        var validator = $("#formSa").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
        $("#formSa").kendoValidator({
            ignore: ".ignore"
        });

        $("formSa").submit(function (event) {
            if (validator.validate()) {
                $('#formSa')[0].submit();
            } else {
                alert("Oops! There appears to be invalid data on the form.");
            }
        });
```

I have disabled TimePicker and then ran Validator. That works, but when I select as time in the dropdown and post, I see that the TimePicker field is a  low values date, January 1, 0001 00:00:00.

I want to exclude TimePicker from Validator evaluation, but I need to keep it enabled for possible user interaction. The other data items on the page, including other Kendo controls, work without any issues. Does anyone know how to handle this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `@(Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(model => model.OverheadRepeatedByDateTime)...` instead. This is how you bind a model property to an input control.

Comment: Hi Supersnake. I am going to give you credit for this answer, but I had to write code to make my scenario "happen." I ended up using a change event on the TimePicker to manually, so to speak, enable/disable the control, which is the only way I could accomplish the task of Validator ignoring TimePicker.

Comment: I don't see how to give credit to Supersnake's answer.